# How to get crash dumps of .Net Compact Framework application running on Windows Mobile / Wince Device

Tags: crash, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have a `.Net CF 3.5` application which crashes and at times the logs don't contain any error (which is the pain area).

The application also loads some third party Managed DLLs. I suspect it could be an issue with some thread created in one of the third party Dlls.

But to confirm the case I would like to have a look at the crash dump.
However, my application is not generating any crash dumps. [Some links on the net][1] suggest that it's not feasible for a managed application to generate crash dumps.

[1]:http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/PocketPC-Developer/32282068/need-crash-dump-from-managed-app.aspx .

But I have a gut feeling that there must be a way to detect the culprit thread and the dll of a crashing managed application.